# How can I view the table/query linked to a form/table/list in Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

How can I view the table/query linked to a form/table/list in Access? It's not displaying in the "Property" pane during the Design View.

This seems simple but it took me a while, and there seems to be only one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely being set in the code (i.e. the RowSource of the List gets set in a VBA module).
Go to Design View and go to View Code:
Open the form, right click on an "empty" part of it, select "Design View". Now click the "Design" tab at the very top, then click "View Code" which should be on the very right.

If it doesn't take you to the correct place, it might be a subform. So while inside the Design View, right click the object containing the data and select "Subform in New Window", and then from there go to the "View Code" view the "Design" tab.